# Email Template Community test email

Tags: email-template, community, merge-field

I need to test an email that gets sent when administrator provides access to the community. I did not use the standard community templates (Changed Password, Forgot Password, New Members Welcome)but created a new one.

Also, the email template does not get linked to the community in the "Manage Community" section.

I used {!Community_Url} in the template. When I try to "Send test and verify merge fields", I can chose the user and the object the email relates to. But how would I link the merge field {!Community_Url} to the community?

Thanks for some explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trying I found that when you test the email template via "Send test and verify merge fields" you cannot test any community merge fields like {!Community_Url}. You need to test "live" in the community environment, as the community info needs to be passed on to the merge field. Also, when e.g. the administrator only modifies an object in Force.com and he is not in the community environment, {!Community_Url} will be empty if an email is triggered.